# Eloquent Javascript require function explanation needed

Tags: javascript, module, require

The author explains a minimal implementation of require function [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html#p_hpfd8nPIk6) that looks like:

```
function require(name) {
  var code = new Function("exports", readFile(name));
  var exports = {};
  code(exports);
  return exports;
}

console.log(require("weekDay").name(1));
// → Monday
```

I am having an hard time understanding what exactly is going on, mainly because the example is incomplete. For now, I have accepted that `readFile()` returns code in string format. The part that is really confusing me: **why is `var exports` being passed into the code, what is it doing, and why is it being returned?** How is `exports` object returning the code that `readFile` has retrieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new Function("exports", body)` will create an anonymous function which takes one parameter (`exports`) and executes the code found in `body`.
The `exports` that will be passed into the function body starts as an empty object, with the intention that the module body will fill it with things it wants to expose to the rest of the world. Then the function is executed (and we pass in our `exports` object). Finally, the stuff that the module exported is returned.

Here is a more complete example:

```
fakeFileSystem = {
  "weekDay.js": "                \
      var days = [               \
        'Sunday',                \
        'Monday',                \
        'Tuesday',               \
        'Wednesday',             \
        'Thursday',              \
        'Friday',                \
        'Saturday'               \
      ];                         \
      function name(dayNo) {     \
        return days[dayNo];      \
      }                          \
      exports.name = name;       \
  "
};

function require(name) {
  var code = new Function("exports", fakeFileSystem[name + ".js"]);
  var exports = {};
  code(exports);
  return exports;
}

console.log(require("weekDay").name(1));
// → Monday
```

This works because `code` is constructed as if it was this function:

```
function(exports) {
  var days = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
  ];
  function name(dayNo) {
    return days[dayNo];
  }
  exports.name = name;
}
```

We pass `{}` into this function, and it will modify it to be

```
{
  name: function(dayNo) {
    return days[dayNo];
  }
}
```

where `days` is captured in the closure, but not visible to the outside world. This allows us to access only the things in the module that were explicitly added to `exports` (like `name`), while hiding everything that wasn't (like `days`).

Comment: Thanks for a more complete example.

Answer (score 2):

This example requires understanding the function constructor.

This might help:

```
$ node
> f = new Function("x", "return x + 2");
[Function]
> f(8)
10
```

In your example, the body of the function is code from a file, in which you will see assignments to properties of the variable `exports`. So what is `exports`? It's an object which is initially empty. The body of the module will "fill it in" when called. After the call to `code(exports)` you will have a filled in object with a lot of good stuff in it, which gets returned from `require`.

Example:

Suppose the file contains

```
var x = 3
exports.y = 10 * x
```

Then your call will pass in an empty object, but executing the function will add the `y` property to the object and you will get back

```
{y: 30}
```

Comment: _"After the call to code(exports) you will have a filled in object with a lot of good stuff in it, which gets returned from require."_ But doesn't `code(exports)` need to return the `exports` argument that was passed into it? Or can this function just change the contents of a variable above its scope if passed into it?

Comment: It can change the contents of the object.